# adding filename object to multer.diskStorage causes ENOENT error in postman

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, multer

When I try to post in my postman api, I get this enoent error
"error": {
"message": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Graham family\Desktop\image-store-tester\uploads\2022-06-09T08:47:04.619ZEq_it-na_pizza-margherita_sep2005_sml.jpg'"
}
However I can assure you that uploads folder is there and it was created automatically by multer.
If I remove the "filename" from const storage the API works, however I need the files I post to have their file extension so that they are useable. I have confirmed that filename is the correct spelling, so I am not sure what the next step is to solving this issue.

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./uploads/");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/png") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(
      //the tutorial put null here instead of an error
      new Error("Wrong file mimetype, accepted types are jpeg and png"),
      false
    );
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
});
```

https://github.com/academind/node-restful-api-tutorial/tree/09-image-upload
Thank you

Comment: Does your filesystem allow filenames with colons (`:`) in it?

Comment: Woohoo! Removing the date from the filename solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue was cause by colons in the filename. Removing the date fixed the issue. Thanks to robertklep for the solution